# Check if string matches any of an array of regexes?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of regexes: `[/apple/i, /banana/i, /berry/i]`.

I also have an array of strings, `str_array`. I want to iterate over `str_array` and output to the screen any string that doesn't match any of the regexes. If it matches any at all it should be passed over.

How could I do this?

Comment: @Jefffrey Sorry, didn't proofread what I was writing. Edited for clarity.

Comment: If you found either answer helpful, please consider selecting the one you valued most.

Answer (score 3):

```
str_array = %w[pineapple orange blueberry]
str_array.reject{|e| [/apple/i, /banana/i, /berry/i].any?{|re| re =~ e}}
#=> ["orange"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid multiple matching against each of the regex you can use `Regexp.union`:

```
regexes = [/apple/i, /banana/i, /berry/i]
union_regex = Regexp.union(regexes)
str_array.reject{|e| e =~ union_regex }
```

Comment: Using `any?` will also do short cut once a matching regex is detected.